# UML: Association with typed class or assigned subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, uml

I am trying to reverse engineer some existing java code, creating a UML class diagram.

Note: `MovingRectangle` extends `MovingShape`.

```
public class AnimationPanel {

    private MovingShape s;

    public AnimationPanel {
        s = new MovingRectangle;
    }
}
```

In my UML diagram, should the association be from AnimationPanel to MovingShape (the class of the instance variable) or from AnimationPanel to MovingRectangle (the class assigned to the instance variable)?

Comment: I guess it should be `MovingRectangle` instead of `MovingShape` (or vice versa)?

Comment: I think it sould be `MovingShape`, then from the diagram you would see that there are many MovingShape concrete classes.

Comment: I agree with Kristian. His should be an answer rather than a comment!

Comment: Yeah, most likely. But it can also be a copy/paste issue since we don't see the source ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The use of navigation for showing ownership on association is deprecated. You should set the the owned property (the small dot) near `AnimationPanel` to `MovingRectangle` like this:

[image]

See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993606/uml-composition-with-bidirectional-association-composing-object-has-back-pointe) with a citation of Superstructures.

Comment: Is there a particular justification for why the composition link points to the MovingRectangle class and not the MovingShape class?

Comment: Its not a composition (which would be a diamond). Its ownership (see my edit with the link)

Comment: Ah, I thought your dot was a diamond initially.

Answer (score 2):

I added:
 - the generalization between MovingRectangle and Moving Shape,
 - the fact that the attribute is named "s" and is private.

[image]